# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit.report_thread'

Tags: deployment, webrtc, report, streamlit, webcam-capture

[image]

Trying to deploy real time emotion detection model and getting this error from streamlit. I tried installing all the libraries but it always throwing this error.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like another versioning issue for streamlit components. The response from Ben in the following should work. Let me know if this helps.
https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/module-not-found-reportthread/5657/2